# Is it possible to display iOS horizontal/landscape alert with SwiftUI?

Tags: ios, swiftui

I need to display an **horizontally rotated alert** while the iOS device is being held in landscape orientation in the user's hands.

Is it possible to do this with an Extension to the Alert struct or some other way?

Comment: It's already rotated by default. Do you want to rotate the alert back to portrait style or something?

Comment: all alerts that I have seen when holding the phone normally display in portrait-mode and display in the same way if the phone is being held in landscape.